# what's the best way to make a ticket based raffle bot

Tags: json, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a new bot and I don't know what's the best way to implement tickets. For example, I want this discord bot to giveaway the prize but people with more tickets have a bigger chance of winning

Example:

Jimmy has 10

Jax has 12

Leo has 22

I would like to make Leo the guy with the most chance of winning.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic implementation:

```js
const {Client, Collection} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

// change this to whatever you want
const prefix = '!'
// a collection of how many tickets each user (stored by their id) has bought
const tickets = new Collection()
// an array of user ids who can draw the raffle
cont canDraw = []

client.on('message', message => {
  const {author, channel, content} = message
  // don't do anything if the message was from a bot
  // or the message doesn't start with the prefix
  if (author.bot || !content.startsWith(prefix)) return

  const args = content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ')
  const command = args.shift()

  switch (command) {
    case 'buy': {
      // if first argument isn't a number
      if (isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply('you must specify the number of tickets you want to buy!')

      const n = Number(args[0])

      // insert logic to buy the tickets with something

      // adds the number of tickets to the collection
      tickets.set(author.id, (tickets.get(author.id) || 0) + n)
      channel.send(`Purchased ${n} tickets.`)
      break
    }

    case 'draw': {
      // only allow some users to draw the raffle
      if (!canDraw.includes(author.id)) return
      // exit if nobody has bought any tickets
      if (tickets.size === 0) return message.reply('nobody has bought any tickets!')

      // this basically sets the chance to win the raffle to
      // (number of tickets you bought) ÷ (total number of tickets)
      const arr = tickets.reduce((arr, count, user) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) arr.push(user)
        return arr
      }, [])
      const winner = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]

      // reset number of tickets bought
      tickets.clear()
      // <@!id> mentions the user, using their nickname if they have one
      channel.send(`The winner is <@!${winner}>!`)
    }
  }
})

client.login(yourBotToken)
```

I don't know if this is the 'best way' to do it, but it works.

---

**Tip for asking questions in the future:**

Your question is more likely to be answered and be well-received if you focus on one particular thing (for example something like 'how do I pick a random item with different weights') instead of asking 'how do I implement x'. Stack Overflow isn't really meant for people to write all of your code for you.

Comment: I find this answer to be contradicting. I think that you basically solved the TS's software related question very well. You also mention that next time he should focus more on asking a singular question instead of "do this for me please" and I completely agree with you. There is no incentive to do so however, because you still answered his question. This has happened a lot in the past and will most likely continue in the future, provided this goes on. Note that this is in no way shape or form meant as critique towards you, just something I noticed a lot happening.

Comment: @Ludo21South Good point. I'll consider that when I see a question like this in the future.